# Error: Use of self in property access 'reuseidentifier' before super.init initializes self

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am new to IOS programming and am trying to understand what the below error is actually telling me and how to fix it. can anyone help with this please ?

Code from my TableViewCell.swift file is added below.

```
import UIKit

class SweetTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet  var usernameLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet  var timestampLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    @IBOutlet  var profileImageView: UIImageView! = UIImageView()
    @IBOutlet  var sweetTextView: UITextView! = UITextView()

    required init(coder aDecoder: (NSCoder!)) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier reuseIdenifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you fix your code formatting and show in the body of your question the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Confusing error message but I believe the issue is your "reuseIdenifier" local parameter name.

Try:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't deep link but look at the External Parameter Name section in the Swift documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

The reason it's giving this error is because you are really accessing self.reuseIdentifier in your init when you using reuseIdentifier because reuseIdenifier is actually the argument in that scope (due to the local parameter name). You can't access a property of self before self is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistype, the `t` is missing:

```
reuseIdenifier
        ^^
```

so in the init body you are actually referring to the instance property, and that's what the error states.

However since the external and local name are the same, it's just better if you use the `#` shortcut:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, # reuseIdentifier: String?) {
```